# Handle different structure of some object in same Airline API

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am working on API but always getting different structure which is mention below.
please help me how to handle.

first response:- when I search result for one-way I am getting below response

```
      "OriginDestinationOption":{
                    "FlightSegment":{
                       "Status":"HS",
                       "DepartureAirport":{
                          "CodeContext":"IATA",
                          "LocationCode":"IST"
                       },
                       "Comment":"",
                       "ConnectionType":"DOMESTIC",
                       "FareBasisCode":"V",
                       "ArrivalAirport":{
                          "CodeContext":"IATA",
                          "LocationCode":"ESB"
                       },
                       "BookingClassAvails":{
                          "CabinType":"Economy",
                          "BookingClassAvail":""
                       },
                       "DepartureDay":"Wed",
                       "NumberInParty":"1",
                       "ResBookDesigCode":"Y",
                       "E_TicketEligibility":true,
                       "RPH":"1",
                       "DepartureDateTime":"2021-12-22T10:55:00.000+03:00",
                       "ArrivalDateTime":"2021-12-22T12:00:00.000+03:00",
                       "ValidConnectionInd":false,
                       "FlightNumber":"TK2118",
                       "OperatingAirline":{
                          "CompanyShortName":"TURKISH AIRLINES",
                          "Description":"",
                          "Code":"TK"
                       }
                    },
                    "RPH":"1"
                 }
```

second Response : getting this response when I search for round trip

```
 "OriginDestinationOption": [{
                "FlightSegment": [{
                    "DepartureDateTime": "2020-10-02T10:05:00.000",
                    "ArrivalDateTime": "2020-10-02T11:15:00.000",
                    "FlightNumber": "2412",
                    "FareBasisCode": "V",
                    "ValidConnectionInd": "false",
                    "RPH": "1",
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "IST"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "AYT"
                    },
                    "OperatingAirline": {
                        "Code": "TK"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "DepartureDateTime": "2020-10-07T21:10:00.000",
                    "ArrivalDateTime": "2020-10-07T22:20:00.000",
                    "FlightNumber": "7541",
                    "FareBasisCode": "W",
                    "ValidConnectionInd": "false",
                    "RPH": "2",
                    "DepartureAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "AYT"
                    },
                    "ArrivalAirport": {
                        "LocationCode": "SAW"
                    },
                    "OperatingAirline": {
                        "Code": "TK"
                    }
                }]
            }]
```

I am using below classes for desterilize API response

```
    public class OriginDestinationOption
    {
        public FlightSegment FlightSegment { get; set; }
        public string RPH { get; set; }
    }

    public class OriginDestinationOptions
    {
        public List<OriginDestinationOption> OriginDestinationOption { get; set; }
    }

    public class AirItinerary
    {
        public OriginDestinationOptions OriginDestinationOptions { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't understand how to use a company's API, or you have feedback for that API, you should contact that company for assistance. We, the general community who have no knowledge of what even API you're working with, can only speculate about why this is happening, let alone give a definitive answer.

Comment: Seems like one request is returning a JSON object with just one `FlightSegment` and another request is returning a JSON object with multiple (an array) of `FlightSegment`, you'll need 2 `OriginDestinationOption` models, one with a `List<FlightSegment>` and another one with just a single `FlightSegment` and deserialize to correct one depending on which endpoint you're calling

Comment: This is the problem I am not sure about the response when it will be List  and without list, Is there any way that convert all response into list either it is list or without list